# Multiple mat-icon registry in Angular 7

Tags: angular7

When I tried Multiple icons, icon which I given First in `<mat-icon>` tag is repeating for all mat-icon tag.

```
constructor(private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
 
     this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon('downld', this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/images/DownloadCloud.svg'));
     this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon('match', this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/images/Match.svg'));
     this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon('openfile', this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/images/OpenFile.svg'));
  }
```

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="match"></mat-icon>
<mat-icon svgIcon="openfile"></mat-icon>
<mat-icon svgIcon="downld"></mat-icon>
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VeSt.png)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late to the party but for confused future readers:

The problem was not to use the registry as a fluent API but the SVGs themselves.

The problem was that the SVGs used the same id and therefore overwrote themselves. The solution was found here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14959#issuecomment-481797135

Answer (score -1):

Correct method below

```
this.matIconRegistry 
.addSvgIcon('downld',this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/images/DownloadCloud.svg') 
.addSvgIcon('match', this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/images/Match.svg') 
.addSvgIcon('openfile', this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/images/OpenFile.svg') );
```